# Problem in python script using ifcopenshell module

Tags: python, bim, ifc-open-shell

Currently i try to run a code but I keepr receiving errors, tried everything to fix error but unfortunatly no results. hoping someone can help me.

```
# Importeer de functies uit ifc_functions.py
import IFCOPENSHELL
from ifc_fucntions import *

# Definieer de naam van het IFC-bestand
ifc_file_name = "Centrale Bibliotheek Rotterdam,IFC"

# Open het IFC-bestand
ifc_file = open_ifc(ifc_file_name)

# Definieer lijst met entiteiten om te controleren
entity_list = ["IfcWall", "IfcSlab"]

# Maak lege lijst voor clashes
clash_list = []

# Loop door alle entiteiten in het IFC-bestand
for entity in ifc_file.by_type("IfcProduct"):
    
    # Controleer of de entiteit zich in de entity_list bevindt
    if entity.is_a() in entity_list:
        
        # Loop door alle entiteiten in het IFC-bestand
        for entity2 in ifc_file.by_type("IfcProduct"):
            
            # Controleer of de entiteit zich in de entity_list bevindt
            if entity2.is_a() in entity_list:
                
                # Controleer op botsingen tussen de twee entiteiten
                if entity.geometry and entity2.geometry:
                    if entity.geometry.intersects(entity2.geometry):
                        
                        # Voeg clash toe aan clash-lijst
                        clash_list.append([entity, entity2])
                        
# Print clash-lijst
print("Clashes:")
for clash in clash_list:
    print(clash[0].GlobalId, clash[1].GlobalId)
```

```
import IFCOPENSHELL

def open_ifc():
    ifc_file = IFCOPENSHELL.open("Centrale Bibliotheek Rotterdam.open_ifc")
    return ifc_file
```

```
from ifc_functions import open_ifc

ifc_file = open_ifc("Centrale Bibliotheek Rotterdam.IFC")
```

the errors that I keep receiving:

[photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFWcT.png)

I get errors and already tried to fix them but with no results.:

Tried different versions of python 3.9/3.10
Installed pip again / upgrade
Put everything into one path

Answer (score 0):

kinda boring error but I think you have an typo here :

```py
from ifc_fucntions import *
```